# Altering Oracle Primary Keys

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

Oracle table may have one or more columns designated as the primary key. This designation occurs at the time that the table is created. Assume the table has multiple columns as part of it's primary key and some of these columns are foreign keys.

1. Can we alter the primary key of the table and make some of the foreign keys null (ie change them from not null to null)?
2. Is it at all advisable to change the primary key of an oracle table after creation?

This is a theoretical question. I am trying to get the advice and experience of the professionals.

Comment: What do *you* think the answers to these questions are, and what makes you unsure of those answers?

Comment: 1. No. Columns that belong to the primary key cannot be null.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter a column that is part of a primary key and mark is as `NULL`(able), but because you have a primary key (P) constraint defined on it, `NULL` values will still be rejected if they are inserted. Primary keys do not permit `NULL` values in their columns:

```
create table tmp1 (col1 integer not null, col2 integer not null, constraint pk_tmp1 unique (col1));
create table tmp2 (col1 integer not null, col2 integer not null, constraint pk_tmp2 primary key (col1), constraint fk_col1 foreign key (col1) references tmp1(col1));
alter table tmp2 modify (col1 null); -- this succeeds
insert into tmp1 values (1,100);
insert into tmp2 values (null,200); -- this however still fails
```

However, you can drop the primary key constraint and create a unique (U) constraint in its place. Unique keys do permit `NULL` as a permissible value:

```
alter table tmp2 drop constraint pk_tmp2;
alter table tmp2 add constraint uk_tmp2 unique (col1);
insert into tmp2 values (null,200); -- this now works
```

However, consider some peculiar behavior:

If a `NULL` value is in the *only* column of the unique constraint, it won't be enforced. You can insert as many `(null,200)` rows as you'd like and it will let you. If however the unique constraint is a *multiple*-column constraint then `NULL` in one of the columns will act like a discrete value and only one `NULL` (the other columns being the same) will be permitted:

```
--Unique key on col1 only:

insert into tmp2 values (null,200); -- this works!
insert into tmp2 values (null,200); -- this works!
insert into tmp2 values (null,200); -- this works!

--Unique key on col1,col2:

delete from tmp2;
alter table tmp2 drop constraint uk_tmp2;
alter table tmp2 add constraint uk_tmp2 unique (col1,col2);

insert into tmp2 values (null,200); -- this works
insert into tmp2 values (null,200); -- this fails
```

*(This is actually rather nice behavior. One can leverage this for example on a type-2 history table where you use start/end dates to version rows, and use NULL as the end date of the current row instead of a dummy value like 12/31/9999. A multi-column unique constraint can enforce that there is only one current row (NULL end date) for each entity.)*

Also, a `NULL` in *any* column of a FK constraint will cause the FK constraint to do nothing. You can insert a `NULL` in a child table even though there isn't a corresponding `NULL` in the parent:

```
drop table tmp2;
drop table tmp1;
create table tmp1 (col1 integer null, col2 integer null, constraint pk_tmp1 unique (col1,col2));
create table tmp2 (col1 integer null, col2 integer null, constraint pk_tmp2 unique (col1,col2), constraint fk_col12 foreign key (col1,col2) references tmp1(col1,col2));

insert into tmp1 values (null,100);
insert into tmp2 values (null,100); -- this works
insert into tmp2 values (null,200); -- but so does this! even though there is no 200 in the parent
```

So yes, you can make some of those columns `NULL` by replacing the primary key with a unique key, but you have to be aware of the odd behavior that `NULL`s cause in constraint columns.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a primary key to be nullable. But a foreign key can be nullable.

The reason is this: the primary key identifies a record that represents an entity in the relation. `null` means unknown, or, in other words, unidentifiable. You cannot have an identifier that is partially or entirely unkown, because that defeats the purpose of having an identifier, i.e., a primary key.

But a foreign key is a reference to another entity based on the relationship between the record which has the foreign key and the record whose primary key is being referred to by the foreign key.

For example, a person table may have a foreign key for workplace_id, which represents the id of the workplace he/she works at, but some people will have no such id either because they are unemployed, or their workplace is unknown.

Therefore you can create records in the person table with workplace_id being null.

So, if your first question refers to the case when you have a nullable foreign key, then the answer is yes.

As about your second question, the answer is usually no, because the primary key is the primary identifier of the record and there could be references to it. Yet, sometimes you are forced to do so and then it's not a matter of advices. When you can do it in lack of references, even then you should think twice before doing so.